# Sql server 2005 and windows 7

Tags: sql-server-2005, windows-7

I have the symptoms in this articles, but I have Windows 7 32 bit, and "Group Policy Management Console" dos not work install due to compatibility problem so I can't follow the tutorial.  Can you help me running SQL server 2005 ?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/941823

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My life become easy when I install Developer Edition!! obviously Enterprise Edition can't work with Windows 7.

If the client components fail to install, try to use "Change" button in "Add and remove programes"